# Power Query - Get the Excel Spreadsheet File Name

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am looking for a M-Function that returns the currently opened Excel Spreadsheet Filename without the directory and extension.

i.e. If the spreadsheet that is opened is located here:
C:\HPCLMHSTLI_930.XLSX

I would like:
HPCLMHSTLI_930

Note: I got this working using a Custom M Function that reads a Settings Table which has two Cells defined with the following:
=MID(CELL("filename"),SEARCH("[",CELL("filename"))+1, SEARCH("]",CELL("filename"))-SEARCH("[",CELL("filename"))-1)
=LEFT(B3,(SEARCH(".",B3)-1))

So I am NOT looking for this solution. This solution just seems like a lot of work and that there should be a more elegant M-Language function that would return the currently opened spreadsheet filename.

Comment: There is no other solution I've seen, though a custom function seems a bit overkill for a single line of M code, like:  Name  = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="NameVariable"]}[Content]{0}[Column1]

Comment: Function myfunc()  //  
    myfunc = Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, InStrRev(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1)  //  
End Function

Comment: That is not M code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't quite follow how you got the path - I guess that is Cell("fileName"), but with a bit of fiddling with M Code, I came up with the following:

```
let
    x = "C:\HPCLMHSTLI_930.XLSX",
    y=Text.AfterDelimiter(x,"\"),
    z=Text.BeforeDelimiter(y,".")
in
    z
```

This seems to do the trick.  Since a file name can have more than 1 period in it, this may be too simple, but maybe this can work if your filenames are simple enough.

But this can be improved by wrapping this in a function in the following way:

```
let
  ParseFileName = (x) => 
    let 
      y=Text.AfterDelimiter(x,"\"),
      z=Text.BeforeDelimiter(y,".")
    in z
in
  ParseFileName
```

and then call that using something like this:

```
let
    Source = ParseFileName("C:\HPCLMHSTLI_930.XLSX")
in
    Source
```

Answer (score 1):

I found two more possible answers.

This first is a bit more sophisticated than the one above.  In this case, we grab the substring starting after the first "\" and the last "."

```
let
    x = "C:\HPCLMHSTLI_930.XLSX",
    y = Text.PositionOf(x,"\", Occurrence.First),
    z = Text.PositionOf(x,".", Occurrence.Last),
    a = Text.Middle(x,y+1,z-y-1)
in
    a
```

There probably should be if statements in case one of these characters are not found.

I found one final solution that could also work in the simpler cases.

```
let
    x = "C:\HPCLMHSTLI_930.XLSX",
    z = Text.BetweenDelimiters(x,"\",".")
in
    z
```

M gives us a bunch of choices on this.

Comment: You can just edit and add to your original answer

Comment: C Tauss - First, I am looking for the M function that returns the file name.
In you example it would be "x = m function that returns File Name". Looking at the other comments on this post it looks like this does not exist. 
Secondly, I was looking to manipulate the file name as you shown with the three Text Functions. I was able to use them to solve that portion of the problem. Thanks a lot!